# List the the name of employee that worked on more than one projects

Tags: sql, oracle11g

There are two tables that would be relevant in this. Workon and Employee. The contents of these two tables are EMPID    NAME    SALARY  DID (department ID) for employee and PID    EMPID   HOURS from work on. The SQL I have written is

```
select e.name, w.pid
from employee e, workon w
where e.empid = w.empid
group by e.name, w.pid, w.empid
having count (e.name) > 1
order by w.pid
```

I have been trying to figure out why this code will not give me employees that work on more than one project. Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your group by was returning one row per employee per project, by definition this could never have more than 1 row

below sql should work

WARNING: i am not sure how this will affect performance of server use at your own risk

following will return 1 row per employee  per workon but be limited to employees with more than 1 workon record (so if employee has 5 workon records, you will get 5 rows with same e.name and then 5 different w.pid values)

```
select e.name, w.pid
from employee e, workon w
where e.empid = w.empid
and e.empid in (
select w.empid
from workon w -- there was a typo here originally
group by 1
having count (*) > 1
)
order by e.name, w.pid
```

Comment: I got the error "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" when trying to run that code

Comment: There is an error with that code with the second from statement it is "from work w" instead of from "workon w"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT E.NAME, W.PID
from employee e inner join workon w on e.empid = w.empid
where e.empid in (select EMPID from workon GROUP BY EMPID HAVING COUNT(EMPID) > 1)
```

The subquery is counting all records with that empid associated to it with more than 1 project, and the main Query is checking to see if the empid from empid table is in the subquery's results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below query.

Here in a variable all distinct count department has been taken from department master table. After that only those employee has been selected where count match with distinct linked department count in relation table.

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
    employee_id int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk_employees PRIMARY KEY,
    employee_name nvarchar(128) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT uk_employees_employee_name UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE departments
(
    department_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    department_name nvarchar(128) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT uk_departments_department_name UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE department_employees
(
    department_id int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_department_employees_departments REFERENCES departments(department_id),
    employee_id int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_departement_employees_employees REFERENCES employees(employee_id),
    CONSTRAINT pk_deparment_employees PRIMARY KEY (department_id, employee_id)
)

INSERT INTO employees
VALUES (1, 'John Doe'), (2, 'Jane Doe'), (3, 'William Doe'), (4, 'Margaret Doe')

INSERT INTO departments
VALUES (1, 'Accounting'), (2, 'Humman Resources'), (3, 'Marketing')

INSERT INTO department_employees
VALUES 
    (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), 
    (2, 2), (2, 3),
    (3, 3), (3, 4)

declare @distinctDeptCount int 
SET @DistinctDeptCount = (SELECT Count(Distinct department_id) FROM departments)
--SELECT @DistinctDeptCount

SELECT Distinct employees.employee_id, employee_name
from employees     
where employees.employee_id in (
select employee_id from department_employees GROUP BY employee_id HAVING COUNT(department_id) >= @distinctDeptCount
)
```

Here is the live demo [Emp. with all Department](https://rextester.com/KLJFST63396)

The output is as shown below

```
employee_id employee_name
1           John Doe
```